# Essential Image of the Derived Functor of an injection functor

Tags: category-theory, derived-functors

Suppose $B$ is an abelian category and $A$ is a full abelian subcategory of it, and the injection functor $i: A \rightarrow B$ is fully faithful with derived functor
\begin{equation}
Di:D^b A \rightarrow D^b B
\end{equation}
My question is about the essential image of $Di$. For a bounded complex $Y^*$ in $D^bB$, if each of the cohomology of this complex $H^k(Y^*)$ is isomorphic to an object in $A$, does there exist a bounded complex $X^*$ in $D^bA$ such that $i(X^*)$ is isomorphic to $Y^*$ in $D^bB$?

What about the case when $B$ is the abelian category of $\mathbb{Q}$-mixed Hodge structures, and $A$ is the abelian subcategory generated by Tate objects $\mathbb{Q}(n), n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What do you mean by $Di$ ? Do you assume $i$ exact or is it either $Ri$ or $Li$ ?

Comment: $A$ is a full abelian subcategory of $B$, so I think $i$ is exact, and $Di$ is its derived functor.

Comment: No a full embedding might not be exact. For example, take the category of sheaves inside the category of presheaves.

Comment: I see! Let's assume $i$ is exact now!

Comment: @Roland What about the example I added? When $B$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ MHS, and $A$ is the abelian subcategory generated by Tate objects $\mathbb{Q}(n)$.

Comment: Sorry I can't think of a proof or a counter-example of the general statement right now. I suspect it does not hold however... I don't know either if it hold for mixed Hodge structures. One would need some non trivial extensions of a Tate object and a non Tate Hodge structure, and a non formal complex of these... This might be difficult to construct...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, for sufficiently bad schemes, say non-Noetherian, complexes of quasicoherent sheaves are not the same thing as complexes with quasicoherent cohomology.